# Getting started with Syntaxnet

Tags: python, syntaxnet

Having downloaded and installed Syntaxnet, how do I go about using Parsey McParseface model in an application? I have used the `syntaxnet/demo.sh`, and successfully labelled parts of speech as shown on the [GitHub Readme](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet#getting-started). How do I now create an python app with this?

Comment: Seconding this. I understand how to get it to "work" by using a subprocess to call the demo script using standard IO, but that just seems horribly inefficient. There has got to be some way to call it directly through python but I'm not very smart and tensorflow is very intimidating to me.

Comment: @GregBrimble I wrote an algorithm that gives a text command to syntaxnet, get the output, use subprocess python to turn it to executive command. this "python app" you meant is  something like that?

Comment: @Nazanin Yeah, that would help. Would you mind sharing it as an answer?

Comment: I might be reviving an old question, but subprocess is an incredibly slow way to go about this. Isnt there a way to do this directly?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753980/how-to-use-syntaxnet-output-to-operate-an-executive-command-for-example-save-a/38444785#38444785) is the very simple and basic SyntaxNet-Python algorithm I used to open a file (with any defined format ) with LibreOffice