# How can i call syntaxnet from python file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, syntaxnet

We have successfully installed syntaxnet and we are able to get the parsed output by calling the command `echo 'open Book, which I have written with laboratory writer, with libreoffice writer.' | syntaxnet/demo.sh`.

Ideally what we want is calling syntaxnet from python file (more specifically from flask) and expose syntaxnet service as api for internal team.

Comment: Here's an answer on [how to call a shell script from python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3777301/how-to-call-a-shell-script-from-python-code)

Answer (score 0):

Apperently it is exactly like the example I have used in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753980/how-to-use-syntaxnet-output-to-operate-an-executive-command-for-example-save-a/38444785#38444785). using `subprocess` module can help you to do call this command in your python file and see the result.
I have explained how to use this module in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37753980/how-to-use-syntaxnet-output-to-operate-an-executive-command-for-example-save-a/38444785#38444785)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can call `syntaxnet` from python. You can use `subprocess` module or simply `os.system` command.

```
os.system('syntaxnet/demo.sh')
```

or

```
subprocess.call('syntaxnet/demo.sh')
```

Both works for me. Make sure to give the full path of demo.sh file.